# Ratio problems on currencies

Tags: ratio

Though both are ratio problems on currencies, one I am getting right answer the way I am solving, where other is wrong. But, I didn't find what mistake I made! Can anyone clarify?

> In a certain country, $8$ rubels worth $1$ schilling, and $5$ schilling are worth $1$ lemuw. In this country, $6$ lemuws are equivalent in value
>   of what rubels?

$8$ rubel = $1$ Schilling

$40$ rubel = $5$ schilling = $1$ lemue

$240$ rubel = $6$ lemue

> In nation Z, $10$ Terble coins equal $1$ Gallok. In nation Y, $6$ Barbar coins equal $1$ Murb. If Galok is worth $40\%$ more than a
>   Murb, what is the ratio of the value of $1$ Terbel coin to the value
>   of $1$ Barbar coin?

$140$ Galok = $100$ Murb $\rightarrow$ $7$ Galok = $5$ Murb

$1$ Murb= $6$ Barbar  $\rightarrow$ $5$ Murb = $30$ Barbar

$1$ Gallok = $10$ Terbel $\rightarrow$ $7$ Gallok = $70$ Terbel

$7$ Galok= $5$ Murb= $30$ Barbar= $70$ Terbel

Terbel : Barbar = $70:30$ = $7:3$

Comment: "Galok is worth 40 more than a Murb" - 40 of what? 40%?

Comment: I am sorry, yes 40%

Comment: As I used $$ sign, and percentage disappeared, which i didn't notice

Comment: Hint: you can use the backslash \ after $, %, & and other special characters to make them show properly. This is needed because TeX has special meanings for these characters. (For the backslash itself use \backslash instead.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mistake is in the second question. While the *ratio* of Gallok to Murb is 140:100, that does not mean 140 Galloks equal 100 Murbs.

The numbers should be reversed; **100** Galloks equal **140** Murbs. (Since a Gallok is worth more than a Murb, right?) Now continue your working as you did to get the correct answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand now. This was a terrible mistake, I was making unintentionally!

Comment: I am still troubling in one thing, can you please clarify? when we say "there are 3 girls per Boy, in a class", we write ration- G:B= 3:2 . but, in case of "100 cents worth 1 dollar", we write C:D = 1 : 100. why is that happening?

Comment: @MahmudulHasan The first statement is a ratio, which translates directly. The second is an equivalence; to turn this into a ratio we need to swap the numbers.